# Can CSS create a multi-colored trapezoid?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am looking at updating a 2005 website That uses two images to create the top and bottom frame of the page. The images are a simple two-color trapezoid shape with a border drawn around each colored area. The bottom picture is identical to the top picture, it is just flipped upside down.

I know how to create a trapezoid using CSS borders like this:

```css
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #889cb0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

and simulate borders using the outline property, but how do you stack the shapes and give them the appearance of being a single picture? Or is there a way to create the picture without stacking individual shapes?

This is what I want:

[image: two-colored trapezoid picture of what I am trying to do]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The CSS approach: transformation and gradient

You can achieve the shape with [`tranksform: perspective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) and a [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient). The gradient can also create the line in the middle. For the outer line, just use a border and adjust its width on the four sides according to your needs.

[image]

Here is a working example:

```css
.trapezoid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(1deg);
  margin: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #889cb0, #889cb0 40%, #465b6c 40%, #465b6c 45%, #d8e0e8 45%);
  border-top: 3px solid #465b6c;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #465b6c;
  border-right: 4px solid #465b6c;
  border-left: 4px solid #465b6c;
}

.flipped {
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(-1deg);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #889cb0, #889cb0 40%, #465b6c 40%, #465b6c 45%, #d8e0e8 45%);
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid"></div>
<div class="trapezoid flipped"></div>
```

See browser support for [3D transformations](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) and [linear gradients](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).

### The SVG approach

Although you asked for a CSS solution, I would highly recommend to use SVGs for your shapes. They are semantically more correct for your use case, scaleable, responsive and offer a better browser support.

Here is a working example:

```css
.trapezoid {
  width: 604px;
  height: 54px;
}

.trapezoid polygon {
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #465b6c
}

.trapezoid .top {
  fill: #889cb0;
}

.trapezoid .bottom {
  fill: #d8e0e8;
}

.trapezoid.flipped {
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-2 -2 604 54" class="trapezoid">
  <polygon points="60,0 540,0 600,50 0,50" class="bottom" />
  <polygon points="60,0 540,0 564,20 36,20" class="top" />
</svg>

<svg viewbox="-2 -2 604 54" class="trapezoid flipped">
  <polygon points="60,0 540,0 600,50 0,50" class="bottom" />
  <polygon points="60,0 540,0 564,20 36,20" class="top" />
</svg>
```

See browser support for [SVG](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg).

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You could use the [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property.

[image]

---

```css
.top {
   clip-path: polygon(3.5% 0%, 96.5% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(3.5% 0%, 96.5% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
   background-color: #889cb0;
   width: 360px;
   height: 20px;
   margin-left: 20px;
 }

 .bottom {
   clip-path: polygon(5% 0%, 95% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 0%, 95% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
   background-color: #d8e0e8;
   width: 400px;
   height: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="top">
</div>
<div class="bottom">
</div>
```

---

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJpBrq) too, so you can play around with the values and get an idea how it works.

Comment: Bonkers! Although this required adding ‘-webkit-‘ prefix to work on iOS for me.

Comment: I like the Codepen illustration and the shape is good. The big bugaboo is the borders. Those are used to outline the content area and unify the site. The code hides the left and right borders which I need. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, well, currently I have no idea about the borders. But since the other answer contains a solutions for the borders, I'll just leave it like this.